# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Assets_ft::content_id()

Tags: assets, error, fatal

I've updated assets from an ancient 1.* version to latest 3* and everything looked ok apart when I've tried to edit a page.
I'm getting the following error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Assets_ft::content_id() in system/expressionengine/third_party/assets/ft.assets.php on line 2467

For many reasons I can't update at the time being the EE 2.5.5 which is currently installed.

Anyone with a suggestion?

Comment: Did you ever found a solution on this? I've got the same problem from a 1.* asset to 3.0.3

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that when EEHarbor updated Assets to 3.0, they didn't test old EE2 versions (since it's primarily an EE3 release). They may offer a download of Assets 2.6 if you ask.